# Why can't I import a file.dat using a program in python (I manage to do it only from the console)?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a file `data1.dat` in the same folder as my `code.py`. This is what I write to import from the data1.dat

```
import pandas as pd

#read data as csv to a dataframe
x = pd.read_csv('data1.dat', sep=",", header=None)
print (x)
```

Then i try to convert it to an array using x.to_numpy but my pandas version is too old. Trying to update it writing: conda install -c anaconda pandas   inside anaconda prompt resolves in this issue:
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'anaconda::tqdm-4.50.2-py_0'.
CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\domyb\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem.
Attempting to roll back.

CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist. C:\Users\domyb\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
Running `conda clean --packages` may resolve your problem. Any idea?

Comment: you are getting invalid syntax because you wrote 'x' outside `read_csv()` method...so use this:- `x = pd.read_csv('data1.dat', sep=",", header=None)`  then in next line  `print(x)`

Comment: Probably because the file extension is not .csv and maybe the read_csv method does not support the .dot extension

Comment: The problem was a typo i did. But now i am trying to convert the data frame i get from pandas to an array. there is a way: x.to_numpy but my pandas release is too old. im trying to update it but im getting some problem

Comment: How are you running `code.py` (the full command)?

Comment: im running it through spyder. But i edit the question now, sir

Answer (score 0):

By default, the path is relative to the current working directory, which can change, depending where/how you execute your script.

If the `.dat` file will *always* be present in the same directory as the Python file, make the file path relative to the current file.

```py
import pathlib
import pandas as pd

this_directory = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent
dat_file = this_directory / 'data1.dat'

pd.read_csv(dat_file, sep=',', header=None)
```

If you're using a version of Python that does not have `pathlib`, you can do this:

```py
import os

this_directory = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
dat_file = os.path.join(this_directory, 'data1.dat')
# ...
```

Comment: Ok sir, thanks, i understand. any idea on how to update pandas or transform the dataframe to an array?

Comment: These sound like separate questions from what is asked in the title. I'd consider asking a new question with those details.